# How to get result from array in which user already selected_city key if user selected_city those will come also come not selected city from CITY MODEL

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

City Model

```
[
  {
    "_id": '1',
    "city":'A',
  },
   {
    "_id": '2',
    "city":'B',
  },
   {
    "_id": '3',
    "city":'C',
  },
  {
    "_id": '4',
    "city":'D',
  },
  {
    "_id": '5',
    "city":'E',
  }
]
```

User Model

```
[
  {
    "_id": '1',
    "user":'sams',
    "selected_city":['1','2']
  } 
]
```

Would like to get result from

```
[

{

  "_id": "1",

  "user": "sams",

"selected_city": [
      "1",
      "2"
    ],

"not_selected": [
      "3",
      "4",
      "5"
    ]
 
  }
]
```

Comment: what output you need??  input ??

Comment: Hi sams Welcome to SO ! Please add some code that you have tried so far.

Comment: these output {"_id": '1',"user":'sams',"selected_city":['1','2'],"not_selected":['3','4','5']}

Comment: i need these output {"_id": '1',"user":'sams',"selected_city":['1','2'],"not_selected":['3','4','5']}

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```js
const cities = [
  {
    "_id": '1',
    "city":'A',
  },
   {
    "_id": '2',
    "city":'B',
  },
   {
    "_id": '3',
    "city":'C',
  },
  {
    "_id": '4',
    "city":'D',
  },
  {
    "_id": '5',
    "city":'E',
  }
];


const users = [
  {
    "_id": '1',
    "user":'sams',
    "selected_city":['1','2']
  } 
];

const result = users.map(user => {
  user.not_selected = cities
    .filter(city => !user.selected_city.includes(city._id))
    .map(city => city._id)
  return user;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I want mongodb query

Answer (score 1):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.coll2.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "coll1",
      pipeline: [],
      as: "cities"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      not_selected: {
        $setDifference: [
          "$cities._id",
          "$selected_city"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is little out of the box way,

little hacky may be,

```
db.userCity.aggregate({$match:{}},
     {$lookup: { from: "cities", localField: "id", foreignField: "id", as: "city"}},      
     //where "id" in localField and "id" in foreignfield are the fields that does not exists in both collections

     {$project:{
          selectedCity: {
               $filter: {
                    input:"$city", 
                    as:"c", 
                    cond: { $in: [ "$$c._id", "$selected_city" ] }
               }
          },
          notSelectedCities: {
               $filter: {
                    input: "$city", 
                    as: "c", 
                    cond:{ $eq: [{ $indexOfArray: [ "$selected_city", "$$c._id" ] }, -1] }
              }
          }
     }}).pretty()
```

I don't know it comes in best practice or not...

but, As you can see in my $lookup stage I have used **"id"** in `localField` and `foreignField`, and **"id"** does not exist in both `users` and `cities` collection,

that way you get all the documents from `cities` collection for the user.

Then in `$project` stage I used `$filter` to filter out the results.

then for `notSelectedCities` I used **`$indexOfArray`** operator, if city is not present in selected_city it will return -1, and compared it using **`$eq` operator** with -1 and then only selected that particular city.

Hope this Helps! :-)